# Changing value of atom vector using swap

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have

```
(def data {:headers ["A" "B" "C" "D"]
                 :rows [["1" "2" "3" "4"] ["5" "6" "7" "8"] ["9" "10" "11" "12"]]})
```

And I have a function

```
(defn replace-value [struct] 
    (clojure.walk/prewalk-replace {"3" "hello"} (struct :rows)))
```

When I do

```
(replace-value @data) > [["1" "2" "hello" "4"] ["5" "6" "7" "8"] ["9" "10" "11" "12"]]
```

I get what I expect.

However, I want to achieve this same result using `swap!` So I tried

```
#(swap! data (replace-value %))
```

but I get the error `#object[user$eval1308$fn__1309 0x6caeefd7 "user$eval1308$fn__1309@6caeefd7"]`

I don't know what this error means nor how to resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#(swap! data (replace-value %))
```

creates an anonymous function with one parameter so it not an error but will not perform the swap until executed. If you try to execute it you will receive an error since `swap!` expects the first parameter to be an atom rather than a map.

It looks like you want:

```
(def a (atom data))
(swap! a #(replace-value %))
```

or simply

```
(swap! a replace-value)
```

Comment: `(swap! a replace-value)` works in the repl, but when I use it in a button eg `[:input.btn.btn-primary
    {:type     :button
     :on-click (swap! tdata replace-value)
     :value    "Change"}]` it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Lee, seem like what you want is 
    (swap! data replace-value)
In your comment of Lee's answer,

I think you misunderstand the clojure's special forms,

```
#(...)
```

is shorthand for

```
(fn [arg1 arg2 ...] (...))
```

According to [swap!](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/swap!), the second of `swap!` should be a function. So your codes

```
#(swap! data (replace-value %))
```

actually means

```
(fn [swap-input] (swap! data (replace swap-input)))
```

and `%` is the shorthand of the argument (if there are multiple parameters, you can use `%1`, `%2` etc).

To fix this, you can change it to

```
`#(swap! data replace-value)`
```

or

```
`(fn [] (swap! data #(replace-value %))`
```

And for your question in Lee's comment

> when I use it in a button eg [:input.btn.btn-primary {:type :button :on-click (swap! tdata replace-value) :value "Change"}] it doesn't do anything

`:on-click` accepts a function, so you should add a `#` before its value, like this

```
:on-click #(swap! data replace-value)
```